# Exclude 404 from monolog

Tags: php, symfony4, monolog

I'm trying to exclude 404 errors from monolog to not be spammed if robots crawl my website.
So I tried this documentation : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-ignore-specific-http-codes-from-logs, but if I'm going on an incorrect url, I'm always receiving a Slack from monolog ...

what am I doing wrong ? 
Is it the level of error ?

Specifications :

- Symfony 4.3.2
- monolog-bundle ^3.4

Thank you for any help you can offer.

```
    slack:
        type:        slack
        token:       '%env(SLACK_TOKEN)%'
        channel:     'it-erreurs'
        bot_name:    'Erreurs'
        icon_emoji:  ":heavy_check_mark:"
        level:       notice
        channels:    ['symfony']
        include_extra: true

    filter_for_errors:
        type: fingers_crossed
        action_level: notice
        handler: file_log
        excluded_http_codes: [403, 404, { 400: ['^/foo', '^/bar'] }]

    file_log:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"

    deduplicated:
        type:    deduplication
        handler: grouped
        time: 30

    grouped:
        type:    group
        members: [slack, filter_for_errors]
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and I ended up solving it like this:

```
        slack_errors:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/
            handler:      slack_errors_handler
        slack_errors_handler:
            type:        slack
            token:       '%env(SLACK_TOKEN)%'
            channel:     '%env(SLACK_ERROR_CHANNEL)%'
            bot_name:    '%env(SLACK_BOT_NAME)%'
            level:       error
            include_extra: true
```

Apparently **excluded_http_codes** as **excluded_404s** option is only available for fingers_crossed type handlers. So to get to avoid annoying 4XX exceptions in Slack I nested a finger_crossed handler with Slack handler.